# How to use GoogleStreetView in Leaflet project?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, google-street-view

I have this codes but last step I have a fail.
map.setStreetView(panorama);----> TypeError: map.setStreetView is not a function

```
var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude); //fenway = wf {G: 40.989025, K: 29.096618000000035}
Insurance.Map.StreetView(fenway);

StreetView: function (coor) {
            var options = {
                position: coor,
                pov: {
                    heading: 34,
                    pitch:10
                }
            };
            var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('streetdiv'), options);
            map.setStreetView(panorama);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`setStreetView` is a method of class `google.maps.Map` not of Leaflet's `L.Map` class. So that won't work. You could take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ALL4k/ which also has the error you describe because it's calling `map.setStreetView` but if you remove of comment out that line, the example keeps working and the error is gone.

Comment: I looked this example :[link](http://jsfiddle.net/ALL4k/) before you said. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Don't know what's happening here but that JSFiddle works for me, except for the `setStreetView` is not a method error but as said you can remove it or comment it out, it keeps working.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to set width style. I set it and it worked.

```
<div id='streetdiv' style='width: auto; height: 400px;'></div>
```